# Delete a result from jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, object, selector

I'm trying to remove a value from a jquery object.
Unfortunately my solution does not work.

Why doesn't it work? And what would be the best way to accomplish this.

```
$elems = $('.a');
html = 'lenght ='+$elems.length+'<br><br>';

var target = $elems[3];

//Why doesn't this work?
delete $elems[target];

html += 'lenght after delete ='+$elems.length;

$('body').append(html);
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPLLR/2/)

Comment: AFAIK jQuery result object are only array-like objects, so they don't automatically decrement the length! (You can do this manually, of course: http://jsfiddle.net/PPLLR/3/)

Comment: Do you want to remove it from the DOM, or do you just want to remove it form the result set?

Comment: I want to remove it from the result set

Comment: @Tim then look at the answer of  `Roman`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the element from the collection, use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (just like a regular array).

```
$elems.splice(3,1);
```

Why does your code not work:

1. You try to delete a non existent index from your array

   ```
   var target = $elems[3]; 
   delete $elems[target]; //the index should be "3" and not "target"
   ```
2. Unsetting a property from the jQuery object (for example the property "3") does not magically update another property (property "length").
   jQuery objects (or collections if you prefer) are not arrays. They are only objects that resemble arrays because they implement some of their functionality.

if you want to remove items from the collection based on their contents, you probably want to [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) them.

```
$elems = $elems.filter(function() {
    return $(this).html().indexOf('3') == -1;
});
```

The above snippet keeps all the items in the collection which do not contain the html string "3".

Comment: This will work when you know the index, but I want to use search for the contents within the object.

Comment: @Tim So you want to remove items from the collection based on their contents?

Comment: @Tim My updated answer does that, and no DOM was harmed during the writing of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$elems.eq(3).remove();
```

See : http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: What is supposed to be: `$elems[target]` ?

Comment: If `$elems[target].remove();` is just a replacement of `delete $elems[target];` then it would result in `Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined`.

Comment: This is the right answer when you know the index but I want to search for the content 3

Comment: @Tim if you say this is the right answer, then you want to remove it from DOM. You should be more clear about what you want to achieve, especially what you mean with `I want to search for the content 3 `

Comment: Yes i'm sorry, replied a bit to soon this was not what i was trying to do. I want to remove it from the $elems var

Answer (score 0):

Use the following.

```
$elems.eq(3).remove();

alert($elems.length);
```

Comment: This would not change the length of the `$elems`. It would just remove the element form the DOM, but would leave the `$elems` itself untouched.